# Retrieving new list has incomplete associated object which was previously saved

Tags: spring-boot, jsf, primefaces, spring-data-jpa

I'm building a little Primefaces application (Joinfaces 3.2.4, Hibernate and H2 database). I want to register a car and immediately (in the same view) refresh a cars `p:dataTable`. All works fine and the table content is updated with the recently car added but one column (which shows Person associated data) is empty.

Entities:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person extends DbAudit implements Serializable{

    //Id and another fields

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "person")
    private List<DbCar> cars;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="car")
public class Car extends DbAudit implements Serializable{

    //Id and another fields

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK", referencedColumnName = "PK_PER")
    private DbPerson person;
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface CarDao extends JpaRepository<DbCar, Integer>{
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class CarServiceImpl implements CarService{

    private @Autowired CarDao carDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public DbCar save(DbCar car) {
        return carDao.saveAndFlush(car);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<DbCar> findAll() {
        return carDao.findAll();
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller(value = "carController")
@ViewScoped
public class CarController implements Serializable{

    private @Autowired CarService carService;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Car car;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private List<Car> cars;

    public void loadCars() {
        cars = carService.findAll();
    }

    public void save() {
        carService.save(car);

        // Reset car object

        loadCars();
    }
}
```

XHTML Page:

```
<!-- Here is register form including a selectOneMenu for choose the Person who owns the car -->

<p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{carController.save}" update="tblCar">
    <p:confirm header="..." message="..." icon="ui-icon-alert" />
</p:commandButton>

<p:confirmDialog global="true">
    ...
</p:confirmDialog>

<!-- Here is cars p:datatTable (value=#{carController.cars}) -->
```

I've noticed that when list is reloaded the recently car saved has incomplete Person object (all fields are null except id). Then, if I save another car the problem is now with the new car and previous cars no longer have problems. But when page is reloaded (F5) all information is fetched properly.

Comment: So you checked if the person object is fully populated when saved? Is it? Tried creating a unittest for the service? Then you can easily determine if it is jsf or spring-data-jpa related. Issues are in 99.5% of the cases never JSF **AND** JPA related

Comment: Debug the return of carDao.saveAndFlush(car); and check if the return have the Person object is fully.

Comment: @Kukeltje When saved the object only has id. Register car form uses `<h:selectOneMenu value ="#{carController.car.person.id}">` for select who owns the car; previously I set person field to a new person object in order to avoid NullPointerException. Unit test result is the same.

Comment: @SebastiánLópez Person object returned only has id.

Comment: If a unit test is the same, the issue is not jsf related

Comment: @Kukeltje I think the same. In this case, is there a reason why the `loadShips` method (called from the controller's `save()` method) returns the associated object incomplete? The transaction used to save the `Ship` object is different from the one used to fetch the objects list so I guess second transaction should retrieve complete entities.

Comment: only one reason: it is not d=saved properly.